# Running NUnit task in CruiseControl.NET always throws errors

Tags: nunit, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

So I'm fairly new to cc.net but like it so far. I have SVN getting latest, MSBuild building but when it comes to running my unit tests, kablooey.

I tried the fixes suggested about fixing references in the GAC, but that fixed nothing. I even uninstalled/reinstalled NUnit but still no luck. Also, my tests were initially referencing NUNit 2.46 but now I reference the same version I have installed 2.5.2. I'm running CruiseControl.NET 1.4.4.83.

Currently I'm running cc.net on my dev machine which is WinXP Pro SP3, with .NET 2.0 SP1 and 3.5 SP1 installed. I don't use VS.NET for the builds, but just for FYI VS.NET 2005 and 2008 Professional Edition are installed on the machine.

nunit-console.exe runs fine from the command line so what's up?

Here's my config file:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
    <project>
        <name>STAR Trunk</name>
        <triggers>
            <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="450" buildCondition="ForceBuild" initialSeconds="120"/>
        </triggers>
        <sourcecontrol type="multi">
            <sourceControls>
                <svn>
                    <trunkUrl>svn://myServerPath1</trunkUrl>
                    <workingDirectory>c:\MyPath1</workingDirectory>
                    <username>username</username>
                    <password>password</password>
                </svn>
                <svn>
                    <trunkUrl>svn://myServerPath2</trunkUrl>
                    <workingDirectory>c:\MyPath2</workingDirectory>
                    <username>username</username>
                    <password>password</password>
                </svn>
            </sourceControls>
        </sourcecontrol>
        <tasks>
            <msbuild>
                <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
                <workingDirectory>c:\MyPath</workingDirectory>
                <projectFile>c:\MyPath\solution.sln</projectFile>
                <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
                <targets>Clean;Rebuild</targets>
                <timeout>1200</timeout>
            </msbuild>
            <nunit>
                <path>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe</path>
                <assemblies>
                    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\Assembly1.dll</assembly>
                    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\Assembly2.dll</assembly>
                    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\Assemblyn.dll</assembly>
                    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\nunit.framework.dll</assembly>
                </assemblies>
            </nunit>
        </tasks>
    </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

The cc.net server log gives this:

```
2009-11-04 11:47:53,841 [STAR Trunk:DEBUG] Running unit tests: C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe /xml="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\STAR Trunk\Artifacts\nunit-results.xml" /nologo D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Acuity.Diagnostics.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Acuity.UnitTests.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\AutoSproc.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Framework.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Interop.HDSECOMPRESSION.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\MetaBuilders.WebControls.ConfirmedButton.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\MetaBuilders.WebControls.ExpandingPanel.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\nunit.framework.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Star4.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\StarCore.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\StarReport.Lib.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\WebControls.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\webdev.webhost.dll
2009-11-04 11:47:53,888 [STAR Trunk:DEBUG] Starting process [C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] in working directory [C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\STAR Trunk\WorkingDirectory] with arguments [/xml="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\STAR Trunk\Artifacts\nunit-results.xml" /nologo D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Acuity.Diagnostics.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Acuity.UnitTests.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\AutoSproc.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Framework.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Interop.HDSECOMPRESSION.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\MetaBuilders.WebControls.ConfirmedButton.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\MetaBuilders.WebControls.ExpandingPanel.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\nunit.framework.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\Star4.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\StarCore.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\StarReport.Lib.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\WebControls.dll D:\dev\automatedTrunk\Star\Acuity.UnitTests\bin\webdev.webhost.dll]
2009-11-04 11:47:55,326 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Multiple
2009-11-04 11:47:55,373 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] Execution Runtime: net-2.0.50727.3603
2009-11-04 11:47:55,498 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] Unhandled Exception:
2009-11-04 11:47:55,498 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.5.2/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,498 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] File name: 'file:///C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.5.2/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL'
2009-11-04 11:47:55,498 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,498 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,513 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,513 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,513 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,513 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,513 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,513 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateInstanceFromWithNoSecurity(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,529 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateInstanceFromWithNoSecurity(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,529 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(AppDomain domain, String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,529 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at NUnit.Core.DomainInitializer.CreateInstance(AppDomain targetDomain)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at NUnit.Util.DomainManager.CreateDomain(TestPackage package)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at NUnit.Util.AggregatingTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe]    at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] 
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [4088:DEBUG] [STAR Trunk C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe] 
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [STAR Trunk:INFO] Task execution failed
2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [STAR Trunk:INFO] Task output: ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Multiple
Execution Runtime: net-2.0.50727.3603
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.5.2/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)
File name: 'file:///C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.5.2/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL'
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateInstanceFromWithNoSecurity(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateInstanceFromWithNoSecurity(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(AppDomain domain, String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at NUnit.Core.DomainInitializer.CreateInstance(AppDomain targetDomain)
   at NUnit.Util.DomainManager.CreateDomain(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.AggregatingTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)



2009-11-04 11:47:55,544 [STAR Trunk:WARN] NUnit test output file C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\STAR Trunk\Artifacts\nunit-results.xml was not created
2009-11-04 11:47:56,263 [STAR Trunk:DEBUG] Supplied output is not valid xml.  Writing as CDATA
2009-11-04 11:47:56,263 [STAR Trunk:DEBUG] Output: ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Multiple
Execution Runtime: net-2.0.50727.3603
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.5.2/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)
File name: 'file:///C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.5.2/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL'
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateInstanceFromWithNoSecurity(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateInstanceFromWithNoSecurity(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(AppDomain domain, String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at NUnit.Core.DomainInitializer.CreateInstance(AppDomain targetDomain)
   at NUnit.Util.DomainManager.CreateDomain(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.AggregatingTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)



2009-11-04 11:47:56,263 [STAR Trunk:DEBUG] Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 6, position 146.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadValueChunk(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.XmlFragmentWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.XmlFragmentWriter.WriteNode(String xml)
2009-11-04 11:47:56,263 [STAR Trunk:INFO] Integration complete: Failure - 11/4/2009 11:47:55 AM
```

After mfeingold posted about fusion log below, here's what I got:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/7/2009 @ 10:26:46 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070001. Incorrect function.

Assembly manager loaded from:  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.6\bin\nunit-console.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:/Program Files/NUnit 2.4.6/bin/nunit.core.DLL
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/dev/automatedTrunk/Star/Acuity.UnitTests/bin
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\2272_633932296067629930
LOG: AppName = Tests
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Download of application configuration file was attempted from file:///D:/dev/automatedTrunk/Star/Acuity.UnitTests/bin/Acuity.Diagnostics.dll.config.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @mfeingold - The fusion logs were helpful. Removing the temp files helped with the issue of nunit-console.exe not running. The other problem was, I'm embarrassed to say, in front of the keyboard. At home I have a D: drive. At work I do not... Although the cc.net config I posted does not show the real paths of the nunit assembly nodes there were references to the D: drive. Ouch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error does not necessarily mean that the problem is with the NUnitCore assembly. It can be that one of the assemblies it needs cannot be accessed. Try turning on Fusion logs - run the fusion log viewer. the logs it will produce will show you more details on whats' wrong.

To run the fusion log viewer open a console window from Visual Studio -> tools menu and type the utility name: fuslogvw

Answer (score 1):

Question: What are you trying to achieve with this configuration:

```
<nunit>
  <path>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe</path>
  <assemblies>
    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\Assembly1.dll</assembly>
    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\Assembly2.dll</assembly>
    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\Assemblyn.dll</assembly>
    <assembly>c:\MyTestsPath\bin\nunit.framework.dll</assembly>
  </assemblies>
</nunit>
```

Are you trying to unit test `nunit.framework.dll`? Just guessing, but couldn't this lead to file access problems?

Anyway this leads to more questions:

- Are you expecting `nunit.framework.dll` to be in the compile output folder?
- How could it get there?
- Did you add it to source control then?
- Where do the `nunit.framework.dll` references in your Visual Studio projects point to?

So many questions although this is supposed to be an answer to your original question.

This is what I would try:

- Remove `nunit.framework.dll` assembly node from CCNET configuration
- Let all your Visual Studio unit test projects reference `C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0\nunit.framework.dll`

Comment: @The Chairman - Sorry I renamed the assembly that I wanted to test to Assembly1.dll. I included c:\MyTestsPath\bin\nunit.framework.dll because when I read up on the NUnit task and it said to reference all the assemblies in the bin of my unit test assembly. I may have read that wrong though. However, I did pull out c:\MyTestsPath\bin\nunit.framework.dll yesterday and the problem still persisted. For the reference in my project. I referenced it from the GAC. You're saying explicilty reference it from it's install folder? Any reason? Is it because on another machine it may not be in the  GAC?

Answer (score 1):

I see from the fusion logs that NUnit appears to have ShadowCopy enabled. In the past, I've run into issues with this turned on.  It doesn't appear that the CruiseControl task allows switching this off so you may have to call the command line tool directly to do this.